# Laravel 8 - Where query with substring

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

In my application developed with Laravel 8 I need to retrieve values from the database according to the field called `identificativoPartita`.

In particular, this field is always valued according to the following structure: `value = "A1_ (sequence of number)"` or `value = "F1_ (sequence of number)"`.

What I'm trying to do is take a substring of the `identificativoPartita` field and apply it to a where clause, but I have no idea how to do that.

This is because I have to check according to the user and then show only the results that match the appropriate criteria

Have any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve the goal?

My code:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

    use Livewire\Component;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\AnagraficaSoggetto;
    use App\Models\TipologiaImposta;
    use App\Models\MinutaPartita;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    class TablePratiche extends Component
    {
        use WithPagination;
    
        protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    
        protected $collection = null;
    
        public $filtered = "false";
        public $connection = null;
        protected $pratiche = null;
        //renderizziamo le pratiche a seconda dei filtri
        protected $listeners = [
            'filter' => 'renderWithFilter'
        ];
    
        // footer filter della tabella pratiche
        public $filter = [
            'anno' => '',         // filtro per anno
            'procedura' => '',           // filtro per procedura
            'inesigibilita' => '',    // filtro per inesigibilita
            'imposta' => '',        // filtro per tipo imposta
            'residui' => '',   // filtro per residui
            'soggetto' => '',
            'cf' => '',
            'assegnatario' => '',
        ];
    
        public $markedRows = null;
        public $nomi_imposta = null;
        public $anni_riferimento = null;
    
        public function mount(Request $request)
        {
    
            // Settiamo la connessione
            if (null !== $request->get('throughMiddleware')) {
                $this->connection = 'tenant';
            } else {
                $this->connection = null;
            }
    
    
            $this->nomi_imposta = TipologiaImposta::on($this->connection)
                ->select('id', 'descrizione_sintetica', 'descrizione_imposta')
                ->orderBy('descrizione_imposta', 'ASC')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
    
            $this->anni_riferimento = MinutaPartita::on($this->connection)
                ->select('annoRiferimento')
                ->distinct()
                ->orderByDesc('annoRiferimento')
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
    
            // recuperiamo le pratiche da renderizzare
    
            $this->getData();
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            $this->getData();
            return view('livewire.table-pratiche')
                ->with('pratiche', $this->pratiche)
                ->with('markedRows', $this->markedRows)
                ->with('anni', $this->anni_riferimento)
                ->with('nomi_imposta', $this->nomi_imposta);
        }
    
        public function pageReset()
        {
            $this->resetPage();
        }
    
        private function getData($exporting = false)
        {
    
            $anagrafica = new AnagraficaSoggetto();
            $anagrafica->setConnection($this->connection);
    
            if (
                empty($this->filter['anno']) &&
                empty($this->filter['procedura']) &&
                empty($this->filter['inesigibilita']) &&
                empty($this->filter['imposta']) &&
                empty($this->filter['residui']) &&
                empty($this->filter['soggetto']) &&
                empty($this->filter['cf']) &&
                empty($this->filter['assegnatario'])
            ) {
                $pratiche = $anagrafica->select(
                    'denominazioneSoggetto',
                    'anagrafica_soggetto.codiceFiscale',
                    'indirizzoPOSTA',
                    'tipologia_imposta.descrizione_sintetica',
                    'importoCarico as carico',
                    'importoResiduo as residuo',
                    'pagatoNormale as riscosso',
                    'pagatoDiscarico as sgravio',
                    'data_assegnazione',
                    'username as collaboratore',
                    'minuta_partita.id',
                    'minuta_partita.id_minuta as id_minuta',
                    'minuta_partita.identificativoPartita',
                    'partita_pagamenti.progressivoRiscossione',
                    'partita_pagamenti.agenteRiscossione',
                )->distinct()
                    ->join('minuta_partita', 'minuta_partita.id_soggetto', '=', 'anagrafica_soggetto.id')
                    ->join('users', 'minuta_partita.id_user', '=', 'users.id', 'left outer')
                    ->join('partita_pagamenti', 'partita_pagamenti.id_minuta_partita', '=', 'minuta_partita.id', 'left outer')
                    ->join('tipologia_imposta', 'minuta_partita.id_tipologia_imposta', '=', 'tipologia_imposta.id');
            } else {
                $options = array();
    
                // Recupero le le condizioni di where
                if ($this->filter['soggetto'] != '') {
                    $options['anagrafica_soggetto.denominazioneSoggetto'] = $this->filter['soggetto'];
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['cf'] != '') {
                    $options['anagrafica_soggetto.codiceFiscale'] = $this->filter['cf'];
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['assegnatario'] != '') {
                    $options['username'] = $this->filter['assegnatario'];
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['anno'] != '') {
                    $options['minuta_partita.annoRiferimento'] = $this->filter['anno'];
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['imposta'] != '') {
                    $options['tipologia_imposta.id'] = $this->filter['imposta'];
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['procedura'] != '') {
                    $options['proceduraEsecutiva'] = $this->filter['procedura'];
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['inesigibilita'] != '') {
                    $options['inesigibilita'] = $this->filter['inesigibilita'];
                }
    
                $pratiche = $anagrafica->select(
                    'denominazioneSoggetto',
                    'anagrafica_soggetto.codiceFiscale',
                    'indirizzoPOSTA',
                    'tipologia_imposta.descrizione_sintetica',
                    'importoCarico as carico',
                    'importoResiduo as residuo',
                    'pagatoNormale as riscosso',
                    'pagatoDiscarico as sgravio',
                    'data_assegnazione',
                    'username as collaboratore',
                    'minuta_partita.id',
                    'minuta_partita.identificativoPartita',
                    'id_minuta_partita',
                    'minuta_partita.id_minuta as id_minuta',
                    'partita_pagamenti.progressivoRiscossione',
                    'partita_pagamenti.agenteRiscossione',
                )->distinct()
                    ->join('minuta_partita', 'minuta_partita.id_soggetto', '=', 'anagrafica_soggetto.id')
                    ->join('partita_pagamenti', 'partita_pagamenti.id_minuta_partita', '=', 'minuta_partita.id', 'left outer')
                    ->join('users', 'minuta_partita.id_user', '=', 'users.id', 'left outer')
                    ->join('tipologia_imposta', 'minuta_partita.id_tipologia_imposta', '=', 'tipologia_imposta.id');
    
                foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                    $pratiche = $pratiche->where($key, 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%');
                }
    
                if ($this->filter['residui'] != '') {
                    $pratiche = $pratiche->where('importoResiduo', '>', '0');
                }
            }
    
            // Pagino e faccio to array alla collection per la visualizzazione in frontend
            if (false === $exporting) {
             // HERE I NEED TO ACHIEVE MY GOAL
                //Mostriamo le pratiche a seconda degli uffici associati all'utente ( A1, F1, A1&F1, niente)
                if (isset(Auth::user()->permessi_uffici)) {
                    if (Auth::user()->permessi_uffici == 'A1') {
                        $this->pratiche = $pratiche->where(substr('minuta_partita.identificativoPartita', 0, 2), '=', 'A1')->paginate(15);
                    } elseif (Auth::user()->permessi_uffici == 'F1') {
                        $this->pratiche = $pratiche->where(substr('minuta_partita.identificativoPartita', 0, 2), '=', 'F1')->paginate(15);
                    } elseif (Auth::user()->permessi_uffici == 'ALL') {
                        $this->pratiche = $pratiche->paginate(15);
                    } else {
                        $this->pratiche = null;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->pratiche = $pratiche->paginate(15);
                }
            } else {
    
                return $pratiche;
            }
        }
    
        //funzione per triggerare l'evento onclick sulla tabella pratiche
        public function clickPartiteTrigger($id, $idrow)
        {
            $this->emit('getPartite', $id);
            // questo evento passa al gestionale-modal-component l'id della pratica
            //in questo modo possiamo prenderlo˙per l'apertura del modal
            $this->emit('getPratica', $id);
            $this->markRow($idrow);
        }
    
        public function filtri()
        {
            $this->getData();
        }
    
        public function markRow($id)
        {
    
            $this->markedRows = null;
            $this->markedRows = $id;
            //dd($this->markedRows);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would say consider modifying your database schema, as you have two pieces of data stored in a single field. It would be easier to concatenate two fields to create `minuta_partita.identificativoPartita` than it would to substring through it.

Next, to actually solve the problem, I would create a scope that uses `whereRaw`, such as `whereRaw('SUBSTRING(table.col, 0, 2)')` or something.

You can apply this on the boot event if it needs to be done every single time.

Comment: I should say, if I understand your problem correctly. I'd be lying if I said it wasn't hard to follow because the context is in another language, but that's not your fault.

Comment: If I can make them clearer, I'll explain the result I should achieve.
I have the field `minute_partita.identificativoPartita` composed of a string of fixed length where the first two characters are always A1 or F1 and the others are a sequence of numbers.
As you can see from my code I've if-else construct to check which permissions the user has (A1, F1 or both) In my queries I have to take the value of the field `minuta_partita.identificativoPartita`, make it a substring to take only the first two characters, that is A1 or F1 and then show the results according to the user's permissions.